# Firebase - Angular - Multiple clauses

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I need something like that, but i dont get the correct concatenation with the for and the push. In fact, i would like to avoid doing multiple queries, one per "palabras[i]". It would be excelent if i be able to go only one time to the database:

```
function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $firebaseArray) {

     var arrayRta = new Array();
     var palabras =  $rootScope.textAreaOfrecer.toLowerCase().split(' ');
      for (i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) { 
           var elementosConI = firebase.database().ref().child("solCompras").orderByChild("palabras/" + palabras[i]).equalTo(true);

            arrayRta.push(elementosConI);
      }

   $scope.solicitudes = arrayRta;//$firebaseArray(arrayRta);


}


{
  "solCompras" : {
    "-KdTUecpbUuWJO_Fbj5Y" : {
      "palabras" : {
        "123" : true,
        "444" : true,
        "123123" : true
      },
      "post" : "123 123123 444",
      "user" : "demo"
    },
    "-KdTcRy_P0rjEpnHwHCC" : {
      "palabras" : {
        "123" : true
      },
      "post" : "123",
      "user" : "demo"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add the words to the list in the database, just call `firebase.database().ref().child("solCompras").push(palabras[i])` for each word.

This is going to be as fast as adding them all in one call, because the requests are pipelined over the same connection. See [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)

Comment: I want to add it in javascript array. Not in database

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to include the JSON (as text, no screenshot) you're trying to read. You can get this by clicking Export JSON in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Comment: {
  "solCompras" : {
    "-KdTUecpbUuWJO_Fbj5Y" : {
      "palabras" : {
        "123" : true,
        "444" : true,
        "123123" : true
      },
      "post" : "123 123123 444",
      "user" : "demo"
    },
    "-KdTcRy_P0rjEpnHwHCC" : {
      "palabras" : {
        "123" : true
      },
      "post" : "123",
      "user" : "demo"
    },